# when to use cross-reference and when use containment reference?

Tags: dsl, xtext, emf, cross-reference

I need to implement a domain specific language. I have a panel and some shapes on it.

```
 'panel' name = ID '('  title = STRING',' bgcolor = Color',' width = INT',' height = INT ')''{'((rects += Rect)| (ellipse += Ellipse)|(arcs += Arc)|)*'}'
```

and each shape has a unique rule with some other features. for example:

```
RoundRect:
'roundrectangle' name = ID '{'
(fill ?= 'filled' (fillpattern?='fillpattern' fillpaint=Paint)?)?
(stroke?='stroke' str=Stroke)?
'paint' paint=Paint
'coordination' x=INT ',' y=INT
'dimention' height=INT ',' width=INT
'arc' archeight=INT ',' arcwidth=INT
'}'
```

as it obvious in this DSL, I used some references. But I don't know this rules is correct or I should use cross-reference in those?
This rule works fine and I receive the correct output that I expected. But I know when a feature is not of the basic type (string, integer, and so on), it is
actually a reference (an instance of EReference),this is a containment reference, although for non-containment references, the referenced object is stored somewhere else,
for example, in another object of the same resource or even in a different resource.
And point is that a cross-reference is implemented as a non-containment reference.
I need to know when I should use cross-reference and when use containment reference?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the difference is as following:
A containment-reference is if you want to reference to the content of a rule so it's just lazy for redefining the rule's content everytime you use the containment-reference.
A cross-reference behaves a bit different: If you use a cross-reference the parser need the user having typed in content of the rule the cross-reference refers to beforeallowing him to refer to that already typed in content.

An example would be a real programming language: A Method call would be a cross-reference as the method of this name should already be declared somewhere in the code because otherwise it doesn't exist. In contrary the normal code would be implemented as a containment-reference as it can be used (for example) within a class, a field or a method and the code you are typing in just needs to fullfill the existance of a few keywords and structures but these are only defined in the parser itself and needn't be defined by the user himself before beeing able to use them.

I hope I have illustrated it well enough so you now know about the difference and the meaning of these reference types.

Greeting Krzmbrzl

Answer (score 0):

Your grammar describes the AST of your language. Therefore, a meta model is derived from your grammar. To describe references between your AST elements you can use containmend references and cross references. A containment reference is used if you want to describe a parent-child relation where the child object is "created" / declared during the parent object is created. A cross reference is used if the parent object points to a child object which is created / declared in an other parent object. To "draw a picture": A containment reference is a top -> bottom reference and a cross reference is a left -> right reference.

For example assume you have a field (`private int field = 42;`) or method (`public void foo() {...}`) declaration of a Java class. This declaration is modeled with a containment reference, because a Java class contains field and method declarations. On the other you have a statement `field++;` within the method body of `foo()`. There you use the former declared field foo and it is modeled as a cross reference.

In general I would say: Any declaration is modeled as a containment reference and any usage of an already declared whatever is modeled as a cross reference.